# How to test a Client and Server app simultaneously?

Tags: visual-studio, client-server

For a final project, I need to build a client and a server app. The idea is that the client will send requests to view and modify some data, and the server has to receive them, accept/deny them, and send the requests to a DB. The server app is an actual server, and to test it, I need to be sending requests from at least 5 clients.

The problem is that the professor never really explained us how to do said testing, so I'm kind of at a lost now. How do you test 2 or more different apps simultaneously in VS Studio 2019? Since it's a client/server, I would assume that if I try to test them at different times, the data won't be able to be sent in the first place if the server isn't active.

Is there a functionality or tool in VS Studio that could help me here? The professor only told us that the optimal way was to have different *solutions* rather than projects

Comment: you can have two projects in the same solution in vscode and run each project individually but run both at the same time

Comment: What about the extra 4 clients? Would I need to open Visual Studio 5 times?